# WPF crashed when grabbing data from webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I'm doing a WPF application where the apps need to grab data from the webservice. The apps can be run in my visual studio but it require more than 5 secs for the data grabbing. However, after i publish it and try on another pc, the apps will crash whenever i click on the search button. Do i need to implement the try & catch method? Any advice?

code snippet for the search button:

```
private void serachBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StoreApi.WebService myApi = new StoreApi.WebService();
    var dbs = myApi.GetStorageInfo(0);
    var query = from p in dbs
                select new
                {
                    Name = p.ProductName,
                    Price = p.ProductPrice,                     
                };

    myProductDataGrid.ItemsSource = query;  
}
```

Image of the crashed program:

[image]

Problem Details:

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3 
  Problem Signature 01: beaconproject.exe  
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0  
  Problem Signature 03: 50dc1b77  
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib 
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929 
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa561c
  Problem Signature 07: 2f1a
  Problem Signature 08: 23
  Problem Signature 09: System.FormatException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here, what does "clashing" mean in this context?

Comment: Crash or Clash? if clash what do you mean?

Comment: can you copy the contents from the errorbox where it says "View problem Details" and post here

Comment: I had updated it in my question, please take a look.

Comment: I think the `System.FormatException` gives you quite a big hint as to **what** could be the issue. From your code example, it's not exactly clear... either provide additional code or debug to see which exact line is causing the issue.

Comment: "System.FormatException" - what formatting do you apply in the grid?

Comment: i only change the dateTime format in my code...is it matter?

Comment: Is it possible some of the data is coming back as null and cannot be formatted the way you expected?

Comment: Try to step through your code using visual studio and figure out where the exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep an error logger which records each step in code. Can be a txt file. Wtire the status after each line executed. Better to have try-catch as well. So you can get more details abot your error as well.